# Speech Services Azure - Failing server connection

Tags: javascript, azure, text-to-speech

I am starting to use the [Cognitive Services](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/cognitive-services/speech-service/) provided by Microsoft. I am particularly interested in Text-To-Speech to [synthesise](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/cognitive-services/speech-service/quickstarts/text-to-speech-audio-file) speech into an audio file.

For this reason, in order to test it, I have created the 30days free trial subscription and I have pasted the subscription key into the [Quickstart project](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/cognitive-services-speech-sdk/tree/master/quickstart/javascript/node/text-to-speech) which Microsoft provides. Nevertheless, when I run the simple code I get the following error:

> Speech synthesis canceled, Internal server error. websocket error code: 1011
>   Did you update the subscription info?

I would like to know why my subscription info, obtained yesterday, which still has 29 days until it expires is not able to connect to the server.

I have tried to contact Microsoft Support but they send me back the same link to the same repository of the Quickstart project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just tried with the trial subscription using this [sample](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/cognitive-services-speech-sdk/tree/master/quickstart/javascript/node/text-to-speech), it works fine.

[image]

You can try with my API key.

[image]

```
Key 1: da159eddaebc433e84a8c6ebc8a39e20
Key 2: 68990a117e1a4285ae8076f3c62fd3b2
```

Remember to replace both **subscriptionKey** and **serviceRegion**.

```
  // replace with your own subscription key,
  // service region (e.g., "westus"), and
  // the name of the file you save the synthesized audio.
  var subscriptionKey = "da159eddaebc433e84a8c6ebc8a39e20";
  var serviceRegion = "westus"; // e.g., "westus"
  var filename = "d:/speech/YourAudioFile.wav";
```

Comment: Yes, i have tried today my code and it finally works. I guess the subscription key was not fully actívated